# Study $\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin\frac{1}{x^2}$

Tags: limits

We want to study the limit $$\lim\limits_{x \to 0^+}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\sin\frac{1}{x^2}$$
It's readily to see that, $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\to +\infty$ and $\sin\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ is bounded,say $\left|\sin\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right|\leq 1.$ But we can not draw any conclusion from the facts above only, since the product of an **infinity** and a bounded variable is **undetermined**, which contrasts the fact, the product of an **infinitesimal** and a bounded variable is **zero**.

How to solve it?

Comment: Here one says that the function $f(x) $ oscillates infinitely as $x\to 0^{+}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x_n={1\over \sqrt{\pi n}}$ $lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}f(x_n)=0$. Take $y_n={1\over \sqrt{{\pi\over 2} (4n+1)}}$ $lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f(x)=+\infty$ implies that the limit does not exist since $lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}x_n=lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}y_n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not exist. As you say, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ will approach $+\infty$, but the $\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ term will oscillate between $-1$ and $1$. Thus the function will take on arbitrarily large and arbitrarily small values as $x\to 0^+$. See the graph here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zakj0go0pm.

Answer (score 0):

Use $a_n=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi/2n}}$ see what happens to the limits for $n\to \infty$. Do a case by chase distinction between $n\equiv 0 (\text{ mod }4)$, $n\equiv 1 (\text{ mod }4)$, $n\equiv 2 (\text{ mod }4)$ and $n\equiv 3 (\text{ mod }4)$.